# How to fill colors in the cells of canvas when mouse is active i.e clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to implement a functionality in Canvas where red color is filled in its cell when I click and the color is removed when I unclick the same cell.Similarly, with the onmousemove.

But, I want to implement a functionality where I click on the mouse and unless the mouse is clicked and its moving the cells keep filling with the color and vice versa.

What I am trying is as follows :

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  #myCanvas {
   border : 1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 
 <canvas onmousemove="moveOverSquares(event)" id="myCanvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>


    <script>
     //debugger;
     var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var color = "#FF0000";
     var gridColor = "#ffffff";
     var gridLayoutColor = "#000000";
     var row_col_width;
     var cells = [];
     var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
     var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
     var flagCell;
     //var flagY;


        var initializeCells = function(canvasWidth , canvasHeight , rows , columns){
         //debugger;
         var outlineThickness = (canvas.width/rows)/20;
      var cellHeight = ((canvas.width/rows)/20)*19;
      var currentX = -(outlineThickness + cellHeight);
      var currentY = -(outlineThickness + cellHeight);
         for(var i=0 ; i<rows ; i++){
          currentY += outlineThickness + cellHeight;
          currentX = -(outlineThickness + cellHeight);
          cells[i] = [];
          for(var j=0 ; j<columns ; j++){
           currentX += outlineThickness + cellHeight;
           cells[i][j] = {};
           cells[i][j].x1 = currentX;
           cells[i][j].y1 = currentY;
           cells[i][j].x2 = currentX + cellHeight;
           cells[i][j].y2 = currentY + cellHeight;
           cells[i][j].colored = 0;
          }
         }
         flagCell = cells[0][0];
         //debugger;
        };

        var findCell = function(cells , x , y , rows , columns){
         
         var i = 0;
         var j ;

         for(var j=0 ; j<columns ; j++){
          if(!(x > cells[i][j].x2)){
           break;
          } 
         }

         for(var i=0 ; i<rows ; i++){
          if(!(y > cells[i][j].y2)){
           break;   
          }        
         }

         if(x >= cells[i][j].x1 && x <= cells[i][j].x2 && y >= cells[i][j].y1 && y <= cells[i][j].y2){
          return cells[i][j];
         }

            return -1;
        };

     var getCoordinates = function(e){
      //debugger;
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
             x: e.clientX - rect.left,
                y: e.clientY - rect.top
            };
     };

     var initializeGrid = function(){
      drawRectangle(gridColor , 0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height);
      drawRowsAndColumns(10 ,10);
     };

     var drawRowsAndColumns = function(rows , columns){
      //debugger;
      var outlineThickness = (canvas.width/rows)/20;
      var rowHeight = ((canvas.width/rows)/20)*19;
      var current = -(outlineThickness);
      var i = 1;
      while(i <= rows){
       current += outlineThickness + rowHeight;
       drawLine(gridLayoutColor , outlineThickness , 0 , current , canvas.width , current);
       drawLine(gridLayoutColor , outlineThickness , current , 0 , current , canvas.height);
       i++;
       console.log(current+"dsadaddda");
      }
     };

     /*var getRowColumnOutlineWidth = function(length){

     }*/

     var drawSquare = function(e){
      
      var pos = getCoordinates(e);
      var x = pos.x;
      var y = pos.y;
      var cell = findCell(cells , x , y , 10 , 10);
      if(typeof cell === "object"){
       if(cell.colored == 0){
        drawRectangle(color , cell.x1 , cell.y1 , cell.x2 - cell.x1 , cell.y2 - cell.y1);
        cell.colored = 1;
       }
       else{
        drawRectangle("#FFFFFF" , cell.x1 , cell.y1 , cell.x2 - cell.x1 , cell.y2 - cell.y1);
        cell.colored = 0;
       }
      }
     };

     var moveOverSquares = function(e){
     
      var pos = getCoordinates(e);
      var x = pos.x;
      var y = pos.y;
      var cell = findCell(cells , x , y , 10 , 10);
      if(cell.x1 == flagCell.x1 && cell.x2 == flagCell.x2 && cell.y1 == flagCell.y1 && cell.y2 == flagCell.y2){

      }
      else{
       flagCell = cell;
       if(cell.colored == 0){
        drawRectangle(color , cell.x1 , cell.y1 , cell.x2 - cell.x1 , cell.y2 - cell.y1);
        cell.colored = 1;
       }
       else{
        drawRectangle("#FFFFFF" , cell.x1 , cell.y1 , cell.x2 - cell.x1 , cell.y2 - cell.y1);
        cell.colored = 0;
       }
      }
     };

     var drawRectangle = function(color , x , y , width , height){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(x , y , width , height);
            ctx.closePath(); 
     };

     var drawLine = function(color , width , x1 , y1 , x2 , y2){
      //debugger;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
   ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
   ctx.lineWidth = width;
            // set line color
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.closePath();
     };
        
     canvas.addEventListener("click" , drawSquare);
     //canvas.addEventListener("onmousemove" , moveOverSquares);
     initializeGrid();
     drawRowsAndColumns(10 , 10);
     initializeCells(canvasWidth , canvasHeight , 10 , 10);
     /*window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
       function handleResize() {
     var w = window.innerWidth-2; // -2 accounts for the border
     var h = window.innerHeight-2;
     stage.canvas.width = w;
     stage.canvas.height = h;
     //
     var ratio = 100/100; // 100 is the width and height of the circle content.
     var windowRatio = w/h;
     var scale = w/100;
     if (windowRatio > ratio) {
        scale = h/100;
     }
     // Scale up to fit width or height
     c.scaleX= c.scaleY = scale; 
    
     // Center the shape
     c.x = w / 2;
     c.y = h / 2;
        
     stage.update();
  }
       
  handleResize(); // First draw
*/
    </script>

</body>
```

How can I achieve the above functionality.Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You must distinguish between mouse clicks and mouse drags. Here is a previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688888/how-to-know-whether-the-mousedown-event-is-occured-on-where-we-want-in-canvas/30690225#30690225) that shows how to tell the difference between mouseclicks & mousedrags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fabric.js.
In fabric.js you can easily manage events. For example see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/qqn7u9f0/17/). In this I created rectangle and add to canvas.I managed mousedown with `canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options)` in it.